# Regex.Replace adding 0 with escape character

Tags: c#, regex

I want to find single digits and add "0" left for DateTime format.

I tried the code below:

```
var match = Regex.Replace(@"2017-12-15T8:15:02.000000Z", 
                          @"([^\d])(\d{1})([^\d])",
                          @"$10$2$3");
```

The problem is c# try to find matched group index 10 (because of **$10** but it must be **$1** and "**0**") how can use 0 with escape caracter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main issue is with the backreference syntax, you may easily fix it by wrapping the group id with braces, i.e. `@"${1}0$2$3"`. However, there may be other problems with the regex later.

It is safest to use lookarounds to avoid such issues and issues with overlapping matches:

```
var match = Regex.Replace(@"2017-12-15T8:15:02.000000Z", 
                      @"(?<!\d)\d(?!\d)",
                      @"0$&");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5Cd%29%5Cd%28%3F!%5Cd%29&i=2017-12-15T8%3A15%3A02.000000Z&r=0%24%26)

[image]

**Patten details**

- `(?<!\d)` - no digit allowed immediately to the left of the current location
- `\d` - any Unicode digit (if you pass `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option, it will only match ASCII digits)
- `(?!\d)` - no digit allowed immediately to the right of the current location.

In the replacement pattern, `$&` stands for the whole match (no need wrapping the `\d` with capturing parentheses).

Answer (score 1):

Use named capture groups:

```
var match = Regex.Replace(@"2017-12-15T8:15:02.000000Z", 
                      @"(?<one>[^\d])(?<two>\d{1})(?<three>[^\d])",
                      @"${one}0${two}${three}");
```

I answer mainly from the point of view of how to get around the issue with distinguishing `$1` from `$10`.  This answer skirts the problem by using named capture groups which can't really collide.

With regard to whether your regex is optimal, check the answer by @Wiktor for more information.

**Edit:**

As pointed out by @Nyerguds in the comments below, we could have also used `{$1}`, `{$2}`, etc., as these are the default capture group names.

### Demo

Comment: You scared me for a second :-)

Comment: oops my hand slipped :)

Comment: You're overcomplicating it. No need for the aliases; $1 is automatically also ${1}, so you can use that.

Comment: @Nyerguds I didn't know this.  I'm a Java person with an affinity for regex questions, so I landed here.  I won't edit, but I welcome you to if you want.

Comment: Ah, no prob. Seems the other answer here already mentioned it anyway.